# How to uniqufy the tuple element?

Tags: python, algorithm

i have a result tuple of dictionaries.

```
result = ({'name': 'xxx', 'score': 120L }, {'name': 'xxx', 'score': 100L}, {'name': 'yyy', 'score': 10L})
```

I want to uniqify it. After uniqify operation `result = ({'name': 'xxx', 'score': 120L }, {'name': 'yyy', 'score': 10L})`

The `result` contain only `one dictionary` of each `name` and the `dict` should have `maximum score`. The final result should be in the same format ie tuple of dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from operator import itemgetter

names = set(d['name'] for d in result)
uniq = []
for name in names:
    scores = [res for res in result if res['name'] == name]
    uniq.append(max(scores, key=itemgetter('score')))
```

I'm sure there is a shorter solution, but you won't be able to avoid filtering the scores by name in some way first, then find the maximum for each name.

Storing scores in a dictionary with names as keys would definitely be preferable here.

Comment: I think you're finding the highest score, not the highest score for each unique name.

Comment: @Gabe, No I am finding the highest score of each unique name. I slightly modify the question. Check it out.

Comment: @Gabe: You're right ... I was misled by the existence of only one name.

Comment: @Tony: No, `itemgetter` is imported properly.

Comment: BTW, `uniq.append(max(scores, key=lambda x: x['score']))` would work just as well w/o importing itemgetter.

Answer (score 2):

I would create an intermediate dictionary mapping each name to the maximum score for that name, then turn it back to a tuple of dicts afterwards:

```
>>> result = ({'name': 'xxx', 'score': 120L }, {'name': 'xxx', 'score': 100L}, {'name': 'xxx', 'score': 10L}, {'name':'yyy', 'score':20})
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> max_scores = defaultdict(int)
>>> for d in result: 
...     max_scores[d['name']] = max(d['score'], max_scores[d['name']])
... 
>>> max_scores 
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'xxx': 120L, 'yyy': 20})
>>> tuple({name: score} for (name, score) in max_scores.iteritems()) 
({'xxx': 120L}, {'yyy': 20})
```

Notes:
1) I have added `{'name': 'yyy', 'score': 20}` to your example data to show it working with a tuple with more than one name.

2)I use a defaultdict that assumes the minimum value for score is zero.  If the score can be negative you will need to change the int parameter of defaultdict(int) to a function that returns a number smaller than the minimum possible score.

Incidentally I suspect that having a tuple of dictionaries is not the best data structure for what you want to do.  Have you considered alternatives, such as having a single dict, perhaps with a list of scores for each name?

Answer (score 1):

I would reconsider the data structure to fit your needs better (for example dict hashed with name with list of scores as value), but I would do like this:

```
import operator as op
import itertools as it

result = ({'name': 'xxx', 'score': 120L },
          {'name': 'xxx', 'score': 100L},
          {'name': 'xxx', 'score': 10L},
          {'name':'yyy', 'score':20})
# groupby

highscores = tuple(max(namegroup, key=op.itemgetter('score'))
                   for name,namegroup in it.groupby(result,
                                                    key=op.itemgetter('name'))
                   )
print highscores
```

Answer (score 0):

How about...

```
inp  = ({'name': 'xxx', 'score': 120L }, {'name': 'xxx', 'score': 100L}, {'name': 'yyy', 'score': 10L})

temp = {}
for dct in inp:
    if dct['score'] > temp.get(dct['name']): temp[dct['name']] = dct['score']

result = tuple({'name': name, 'score': score} for name, score in temp.iteritems())
```