# How to make single from multiple element?

Tags: python

```
l =  [{'name': 'abc', 'marks': 50}, {'name': 'abc', 'marks': 50}]
```

I want to uniqify the dictionary result.

```
 result = [{'name': 'abc', 'marks': 50}]
```

Comment: So, is not it the same you asked before? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665414/how-to-uniqufy-the-tuple-element

Answer (score 5):

Normally, the easiest way to make a `list` only have unique elements is to convert it to a `set`, assuming:

- The list entries [are *hashable*](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/glossary.html)
- You don't care about the order of the items

However, a `dict` isn't hashable so in your case it might be easiest just to this by hand:

```
>>> l =  [{'name': 'abc', 'marks': 50}, {'name': 'abc', 'marks': 50}]
>>> l2 = []
>>> for d in l:
...     if not d in l2:
...         l2.append(d)
...
>>> l2
[{'name': 'abc', 'marks': 50}]
```

The code above assumes you want to "uniquify" based on exactly matching `dict` items.  For example, if you have two items with the same `name` but different `marks` they will both be added to the list.